Proof of a Limit related to Gauss' Convergence test
So this is the question:
if the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is such that $$\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} = 1 + \frac pn  + \alpha_n$$ and the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \alpha_n$ converges absolutely, then $a_n\sim \frac{c}{n^p}$
and that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ and it converges absolutely for $p>1$ and diverges for $p \leq 1$

Here is my failed attempt
$$\text{let} \:c_n=\ln(\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}})=\ln(\alpha_n+\frac{p}{n}+1)\le \alpha_n+\frac{p}{n} $$
$$\implies \sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i={\ln(b_1)}-{\ln(b_{n+1})}=\ln\prod_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha_i+\frac{p}{i}+1)$$
$$\le\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i+p\sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1i$$
Although I applied the inequality, it seems that it doesn't work.
And I have absolutely no idea how to continue this? Could you help me?
Edit:
I also noticed that a similar question has already been asked here Gauss' test for Convergence
And nobody answered.

You arrived at
\begin{align}
\ln b_0 - \ln b_n
&= \ln \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (1 + \frac{p}{i} + \alpha_i) \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \ln(1 + \frac{p}{i} + \alpha_i) \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (\frac{p}{i} + \alpha_i) + o(1) \\
&= p H_n + \sum_{i=0}^\infty \alpha_i \underbrace{{}-\frac{p}{n} - \sum_{i=n}^\infty \alpha_i}_{=o(1)} + o(1) \\
&= p (\ln n + \gamma) + c_1 + o(1) \\
\end{align}
where $c_1 = \sum_{n\geq0} \alpha_n$ which exists by the absolute convergence test, and $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.
Which means that
$$
\ln b_n = -p \ln n + c_2 + o(1),
$$
where $c_2 = \ln b_0 -p\gamma - c_1$. Or in other words,
$$
b_n = \frac{e^{c_2 + o(1)}}{n^p} \sim \frac{c_3}{n^p}.
$$
where $c_3 = e^{c_2}$.

Hi there are lots of structural problems and typos, could you fix it?

How did it go for $\alpha_i$ to be summed from $n-1$ to $\infty$, I think you made a typo or structural issue

You should take the limit separately

Could you elaborate on what does $\gamma$ supposed to mean?

$H_n=\gamma +\log \left({n}\right)+\frac{1}{2
n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$

yes and $\frac1{2n}$ is $o(1)$.

Please check the correction I proposed for you!

You didn't understand that $H_{n-1} \sim H_n$.

Oh okay, I didn't.
